# How to message one channel in every server with a timeout?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a command that sends a message in every single server, but I can't seem to find a channel correctly
Here's what I'm using:

```js
    const guilds = client.guilds.cache.map((guild) => guild);
    guilds.forEach((guild) => {
const channel =
          guild.channels.cache.find((channel) => channel.name === "general") ||
          guild.channels.cache.first();
if (channel) {
// send message
    });
```

returns the error: `channel.send is not a function`

I'm also aware sending a message to over 50 channels would also get me rate limited so I was also wondering how I would approach setting a timeout of maybe 5 or so seconds before sending a message to another server.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is filter the guild channels collection for the first one where your bot has access to send messages. You would also need to filter for text channels as you cant send a message to categories or voice channels.

```js
const firstAvailableChannel = guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has("SEND_MESSAGES") && channel.type == 'GUILD_TEXT').first();

firstAvailableChannel.send('This is a message');
```